# Что такое интерфейсы wlan0,eth0. Почему у меня нету wlan0 в iwconfig? Как вывести список вай-фай сетей через терминал?

Tags: linux, debian, kali-linux

Что такое интерфейсы wlan0,eth0. Почему у меня нету wlan0 в iwconfig? Как вывести список вай-фай сетей через терминал?

Comment: Именование интерфейсов может быть другим и у вас не будет wlan0. Примерно посмотреть на интерфейсы для WiFi можно через iwconfig

Comment: это «поттеризм». см. https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/

Comment: Там написано no wireless extension. Хотя у меня только вай фай сеть и интернет на виртуалке - в кали работает. В чём дело?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, это устаревшие данные. Не все драйверы поддерживают старый протокол WEXT. С новым работает команда `iw`. Но самым переносимым вариантом является утилита `ip`. `ip link list` покажет все сетевые интерфейсы.

Comment: Непонятно, что вы подразумеваете под *списком вай-фай сетей*. Это список сетевых карт Wi-Fi или список доступных точек доступа Wi-Fi? Обновите вопрос.

Comment: ip link list: 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:e9:2c:8a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:f8:89:aa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Comment: хочу вывести список wi fi точек

Comment: wifi точки (видимо, точки доступа, access points), не имеют никакого (прямого) отношения к сетевым адаптерам. вопрос абсолютно непонятен.

Comment: @DoctorShader, из вывода `ip link list` следует, что либо у вас отсутствует Wi-Fi интерфейс в принципе, либо его имя одно из *ethX* (*X* = 0, 1).